# How I can names of all tags in gtk.TexTagTable?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I guess that for this used [`foreach()`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktexttagtable.html#method-gtktexttagtable--foreach) function, but can't understand how its works.

Comment: Yes I try write plugin for Gajim. But if you know how do it on C it can help me understand how do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of how to use the foreach method of Gtk.TextTagTable:

```
tagtable = self.textbuffer.props.tag_table

def foreach_func(tag, data):
    print tag.props.name

tagtable.foreach(foreach_func, None)
```

Remember that you cannot modify the tagtable while iterating over it, so you cannot delete a tag within your foreach_func

Answer (score 1):

You can run a loop through the table like:

```
for iterating_var in sequence:
   statements(s)
   # Do something
```

Comment: TypeError: 'gtk.TextTagTable' object is not iterable